# Why does DateTime.Now.ToString("u") not work?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datetime, utc

I am currently in [British summer time](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/eu/bst.html) which is UTC +1 Hour. I confirmed my PC is correct with the following code and it returns true.

```
System.TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(Date.Now)
```

My question is then why does the UTC formatter not work as I would expect:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("u")
```

It returns the exact current system date as below in UTC format as expected but with the Z ([Zulu Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_time#Time_zones)) at the end not +01:00?

i.e.

```
2009-05-27 14:21:22Z
```

not

```
2009-05-27 14:21:22+01:00
```

Is this correct functionality?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

MSDN states the following:

> Represents a custom date and time format string defined by the DateTimeFormatInfo.UniversalSortableDateTimePattern property. The pattern reflects a defined standard and the property is read-only. Therefore, it is always the same, regardless of the culture used or the format provider supplied. The custom format string is "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z'".
>
> When this standard format specifier is used, the formatting or parsing operation always uses the invariant culture.
>
> **Formatting does not convert the time zone for the date and time object. Therefore, the application must convert a date and time to Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) before using this format specifier.**

You should use the following code to convert your current Date to UTC before formatting it:

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("u")
```

or

```
DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("u")
```

To display in the format you expected (i.e. 2009-05-27 14:21:22+01:00), you would need to use a custom date format:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:sszzz");
```

Answer (score 8):

"u" is the Universal sortable date/time pattern, not UTC format; To quote the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx):

> Represents a custom date and time format string defined by the DateTimeFormatInfo..::.UniversalSortableDateTimePattern property. The pattern reflects a defined standard and the property is read-only. Therefore, it is always the same, regardless of the culture used or the format provider supplied. The custom format string is "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z'".
>
> When this standard format specifier is used, the formatting or parsing operation always uses the invariant culture.
>
> Formatting does not convert the time zone for the date and time object. Therefore, the application must convert a date and time to Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) before using this format specifier.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("u").