# WebClient SendValues() method changes datetime value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, webclient

I use WebClient class to send a response acknowledge message in an mvc 3 project. Message is sending from one action method on a project to another projects action method.
Surprisingly the date parameter is  3 hours later, on recieving data.

For example if my sending date is receving data is "2012-08-14 13:42:50Z" i see "2012-08-14 16:42:50Z" on the other side.
Here is a simplified code sample of my case;

```
NameValueCollection ack = new NameValueCollection();
ack.Add("RESID", form.RESPONSE.ID.ToString());
ack.Add("A_DateTime", DateTime.Now.ToString("u")); //2012-08-14 13:42:50Z

using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    var result = client.UploadValues("http://localhost:11578/HPM/ResponseAck", ack);
}



//HPM Controller:
ResponseAck(HttpPostResponseAckMessage response)
{
    //Here response.Date vale is 2012-08-14 16:42:50Z  ???
}
```

It seems to me its about sneaky little serialization monsters changing it cause of some culture specific issue. But i don't know the real cause so the solution.

Edit:

```
public class HttpPostResponseAckMessage
{
    public int RESID { get; set; }

    public DateTime A_DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sounds to me like a `DateTimeKind` issue parsing `HttpPostResponseAckMessage`...

Comment: It might be a problem with `"u"` passed to `ToString`. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915693/why-does-datetime-now-tostringu-not-work

Comment: "2012-08-14 13:42:50Z" is a fine format it seems but maybe mvc model binder parse is the issue. But i dont know where this 3 hours coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think its about expecting mvc model binder to parse a formated datetime.

With the "u" format model binder thinks the datetime is UTC.

So my solution will be changing the type of property A_DateTime to string and will parsing it internaly.

Hope this helps someone else like me. 
Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

You should either change the culture of the current thread or convert and process all dates in  a fixed format such as UTC.
You can change the current culture of the thread using the following code:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-EN");
```

Comment: I was suspicious about thread culture too. My both project's culture is {tr-TR}. Why would it be a problem ?

Comment: No (hayır), just check the current culture of the application while debugging. Most probably, the culture of the thread is tr-TR. Can you check the culture of the current thread in both sides?